# Слитно-раздельно

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Не( )рассмотренный в установленный срок счет перейдет в разряд одобренных счетов.

Comment: Максим, а вы предыдущий мой ответ вам читали? Если да, перечитайте его ещё раз. Здесь, если что, стоит применить то же правило.

Comment: Нравятся участники, не собирающиеся вступать в диалог или хотя бы отвечать, но при этом активно пользующиеся нашими знаниями и отзывчивостью.

Comment: Игорь, большое спасибо, что ответили. Я новичок, не разобрался пока как ответить и вступить в диалог, пока только как задать вопрос.

Comment: Максим, хорошо. Пожалуйста, если вас удовлетворил ответ, можете поставить ему стрелочку вверх, а если он решил ваш вопрос — нажмите на галочку. Это благодарность для отвечающего! Удачи вам на нашем дружном форуме!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Не рассмотренный в установленный срок счет перейдет в разряд одобренных счетов.***

Пишем раздельно, потому что у причастия есть зависимые слова:

Не рассмотренный (когда?) — в установленный срок.